# Creating new columns from existing categorical column in python

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use this table to extract the[image] new columns Profession_category and Age_category.

My expected output suppose to have something like this
Where the folowing professions are Civil Engineer, Electrical Engineer falls as Engineer
Software Developer, Data Engineer,  falls as Computing
Nurse, Doctor falls as Health
the rest falls as 'Others'

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First I have defined a dictionary related to each *Profession* and use [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method to create a new column called `"Profession_category"`, now is a bit confusing to define `"Age_category"` because they are in a specific range but I don't know how to calculate, I used [`numpy.histogram`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) and pass `df["Age"]` as *input data* and Age range as `b` to `bins`, "*bins is a sequence, it defines a monotonically increasing array of bin edges, including the rightmost edge, allowing for non-uniform bin widths*", another options is to use a customized `labels` and an age range.

```py
import pandas as pd

values = {'Civil Engineer': 'Engineer', 
          'Electrical Engineer': 'Engineer', 
          'Software Developer':'Computing', 
          'Data Engineer' : 'Computing',
          'Nurse': 'Healt', 
          'Doctor': 'Healt'}

df["Profession_category"] = df["Profession"].apply(lambda x: values[x] if x in values else 'Others')

#b = [-1,15,40,60,80]
#df["Age_category"] = np.histogram(df['Age'], bins=b)[0].tolist()

bins= [i for i in range(15, 90, 10)]
labels = ['15-25','25-35','35-45', '45-55','55-65', '65-75', '75-85']
df['Age_category'] = pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=bins, labels=labels, right=False)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. The professional_category works perfectly well.